# Data loss on `fread()` due to coercing NA to character

Tags: r, data.table

I am reading data files with `fread()`. For some files, I have the following situation:

```
dt1 <- fread('colA colB colC
             A01 NA NA
             A02 NA NA
             A03 NA NA
             A04 NA NA
             A05 NA NA
             A06 NA NA
             A07 bbb NA
             A08 NA ccc
             A09 NA NA
             A10 NA NA
             A11 NA NA
             A12 NA NA
             A13 NA NA
             A14 NA NA
             A15 NA NA
             A16 NA NA
             A17 NA NA
             A18 NA NA
             ')
```

`Bumped column 2 to type character on data row 7, field contains 'bbb'.
Coercing previously read values in this column from logical, integer
or numeric back to character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00'
and '000' occurred before they will now be just '0', and there may be
inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and ',NA,' too (if they
occurred in this column before the bump). If this matters please rerun
and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this column. Please note that
column type detection uses the first 5 rows, the middle 5 rows and the
last 5 rows, so hopefully this message should be very rare. If
reporting to datatable-help, please rerun and include the output from
verbose=TRUE.`

```
dt1
#     colA colB colC
# 1:   A01        NA
# 2:   A02        NA
# 3:   A03        NA
# 4:   A04        NA
# 5:   A05        NA
# 6:   A06        NA
# 7:   A07  bbb   NA
# 8:   A08   NA  ccc
# 9:   A09   NA   NA
# 10:  A10   NA   NA
```

In the resulting data.table, colB values before the first character occurence are empty strings instead of `NA`. I don't know column names or column numbers in advance, so I can't use `colClasses` argument. Is there any way to solve this (besides using `read.table()` instead of `fread()`)?

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: @EJP, I considered this as a quote of error message - what is correct formatting for that case? without formatting it looks like my own text which  makes it less clear

Comment: I put code formatting then (still don't see what was the problem of quote formatting - it looked better, imho)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given comments to my first answer :

```
fread(DT, colClasses="character")
```

will read all columns as character. Standard R recyling of a singleton. In this case it is not known up front which columns (either by name or by number) have this issue, so reading all as character is acceptable.

Comment: yes, solves my specific case, but in general adds more hassle with numeric fields later, so it would be great if this issue could be somehow addressed at some future releases. Thanks!

Comment: @VasilyA Sure, I'll give it some thought. We like to be more responsive and amenable than any closed source vendor.  And you can make the change yourself if you want, immediately without any restriction. Despite RStudio and Hadley choosing not to contribute to fread and share the effort.

Comment: I highly appreciate this attitude, always feel grateful for the great package as well as your datacamp courses.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* pass column *numbers* to `colClasses`.

See the extensive examples documented at the bottom of `?fread` :

```
# colClasses
data = "A,B,C,D\n1,3,5,7\n2,4,6,8\n"
fread(data, colClasses=c(B="character",C="character",D="character"))  # as read.csv
fread(data, colClasses=list(character=c("B","C","D")))    # saves typing
fread(data, colClasses=list(character=2:4))     # same using column numbers

# drop
fread(data, colClasses=c("B"="NULL","C"="NULL"))   # as read.csv
fread(data, colClasses=list(NULL=c("B","C")))      # 
fread(data, drop=c("B","C"))      # same but less typing, easier to read
fread(data, drop=2:3)             # same using column numbers

# select
# (in read.csv you need to work out which to drop)
fread(data, select=c("A","D"))    # less typing, easier to read
fread(data, select=c(1,4))        # same using column numbers
```

Comment: sorry, I was not clear when writing- I don't know column numbers either

Comment: @VasilyA Well, sadly for me, I have to suggest `readr` then. Maybe that works for you?

Comment: there's no way to set `colClasses` to `character` for *all* columns without using their names/numbers?

Comment: @VasilyA sure there is, `colClasses="character"`.  The singleton gets recycled.

Comment: ah, so simple, thanks! This can be an acceptable workaround for my case.